# Taking React State (object of objects(example inside)) and getting an array of objects to map() for component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the below state of my App how can I convert it to an array of objects that I can map() to iterate over and render child components?

Project focus is to provide a front end UI for a greenhouse climate control system.  Reactjs frontend.

```
    this.state = {
      greenhousesById: {
        0: {
          name: "Mercury",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [0],
          heater: [0]
        },
        1: {
          name: "Venus",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [1],
          heater: [1]
        },
        2: {
          name: "Earth",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [2],
          heater: [2]
        }
      },

      allGreenhouses: [0, 1, 2]
    };
  }
```

Plan is to use allGreenhouses as id's then pull those id'd objects from state to create a new array of objects so that I can render then as Greenhouse component (using the id as key in the child components).

Expected result would be [{obj1Data},{obj2Data},{obj3Data}].  I hope this is concise enough, this is my first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be use `map()` for your `allGreenhouses`

**DEMO**

```js
var state = {
  greenhousesById: {
    0: {
      name: "Mercury",
      temperature: 72,
      humidity: 60,
      fans: [0],
      heater: [0]
    },
    1: {
      name: "Venus",
      temperature: 72,
      humidity: 60,
      fans: [1],
      heater: [1]
    },
    2: {
      name: "Earth",
      temperature: 72,
      humidity: 60,
      fans: [2],
      heater: [2]
    }
  },

  allGreenhouses: [0, 1, 2]
};

console.log(state.allGreenhouses.map(v=>state.greenhousesById[v]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Object#values()` method for this. In your render method, access your state and pass `greenhousesById` to Object.values(). This returns the values of `greenhousesById` as an array which you can then call `map()` on to render each list item:

```js
// Your component state
var state = {
      greenhousesById: {
        0: {
          name: "Mercury",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [0],
          heater: [0]
        },
        1: {
          name: "Venus",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [1],
          heater: [1]
        },
        2: {
          name: "Earth",
          temperature: 72,
          humidity: 60,
          fans: [2],
          heater: [2]
        }
      },

      allGreenhouses: [0, 1, 2]
    };
    
  // In your render method, access your state and pass greenhousesById
  // to Object.values(). Call map() to render each value as list item.
  var result = Object.values(state.greenhousesById);

  console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps!